# how to update user profile using nodejs and mongoose

Tags: angular

On the client side the user can update their profile through a form where the data is sent via form to the nodejs express backend. I want to use mongoose to update the user info. Here is what I have so far:

```
app.get("/api/users/:id", authJwt.verifyToken, function(req, res, next) {
User.findOneById(req.userId)({
    userId: req.body.userId
}).exec((err, user) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err });
    return;
  }
  if (user) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "not user found" });
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and i'm going to change (nom,prenom,email,password,phone,categorieClient) :

```
    const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

// Update a user identified by the userId in the request
    exports.update = (req, res) => {
// Validate Request
if(!req.body.nom) {
    return res.status(400).send({
        message: "user content can not be empty"
    });
}

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password , salt);
console.log(hash)
// Find user and update it with the request body
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userId, {
    nom : req.body.nom || "Untitled user ",
    prenom : req.body.prenom ,
    email :req.body.email ,
    password : hash ,
    phone :req.body.phone ,
    categorieclient :req.body.categorieclient 
}, {new: true})
.then(note => {
    if(!note) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "user not found with id " + req.params.userId
        });
    }
    res.send(note);
    
}).catch(err => {
    if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "user not found with id " + req.params.userId
        });                
    }
    return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error updating user with id " + req.params.userId
    });
});
```

};

Comment: Can u share your route code for it plz thanks in advance.